# How to relate a View to a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am in the process of converting an Android app to use fragments so as to support tablets in landscape mode.

There are two activities that I want to display side-by-side on a tablet in landscape mode. Currently, the first activity (DisplayNotams) has a button that calls an intent to display the second (Chart). The first is a text display of individual items, using a pager to view them one at a time, and the second is a chart on which the items are plotted.

The Chart does not use an xml layout file, as it creates its own ChartView thus:

```
ChartView mView;
mView = new ChartView(this, mCentreLat, mCentreLong, mRadius);
setContentView(mView);
```

(The class ChartView extends View, and contains most of the drawing code.)

I am using the github example commonsguy/cw-omnibus/LargeScreen/EU4you to base my revised code on. The problem (for me) is that this uses different layout xml files in layout and layout-large-land to distinguish between the two. Since I only have a layout xml file for DisplayNotams, and none for Chart, I am at a loss as to how to proceed.

Is there any way I can adapt the example to my situation?

For reference, the two xml files in EU4You are as follows.

In layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/countries"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

In layout-large-land:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/countries"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

'countries' would correspond to my DisplayNotams, and 'details' would correspond to my Chart.

**Thanks to those who answered. This is what I came up with,** replacing

```
ChartView mView;
mView = new ChartView(this, mCentreLat, mCentreLong, mRadius);
setContentView(mView);
```

with

```
ChartView mView;
mView = new ChartView(this, mCentreLat, mCentreLong, mRadius);
setContentView(R.layout.chart);
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.chart_frame);
fl.addView(mView);
```

and creating a new chart.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a group of `addView` functions available to `ViewGroup`. You can use that to add children to the `FrameLayout`s.

```
ChartView mView;
mView = new ChartView(this, mCentreLat, mCentreLong, mRadius);

FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.countries);
frame.addView(mView);
```

Comment: Yes - I just came back here to say I found that out for myself, thanks! I tried putting ViewGroup inside my newly-created xml file and got an exception, then I discovered FrameLayout derives from ViewGroup. Problem solved. I'll edit my question with my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `setContentView(mView)` you can return your ChartView in the `onCreateView`-Method of your Fragment Class:

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ChartView mView;
            mView = new ChartView(this, mCentreLat, mCentreLong, mRadius);
            return mView;
        }
```

Comment: This may well be something to look at when I get round to implementing the fragment side, thanks. For now, I was looking for a way to get my ChartView inside some sort of xml container - which turned out to be FrameLayout.